# jquery autocomplete json

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to have a autocomplete input on my form and I'm having problems getting the data to display. There are a ton of posts on this but also what seems like as many different ways of doing it. I've been trying to follow the examples on the jquery site but I guess I'm just not getting the return data correct? My page looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">                                         
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#Codes" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({                   
                   url: "/jreqlib",
                   dataType: "json",
                   data: {
                       featureClass: "P",
                       style: "full",
                       maxRows: 25,
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item.name,
                                value: item.name
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
   });
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input id="Codes">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm returning from the server looks like this:

```
[{"1234":"1234"},{"134":"134},{"567":"567"}]
```

What I would love is when I click in the box, it shows me "1234" and "567" and if I type 1 then  "1234" and "134" would appear, if i type in 12 then just "1234" would appear ect.

Any help would be appreciated
TIA

Comment: I haven't used the autocomplete from jquery before It looks like you are trying to use item.name but your json doesn't contain name.

Comment: I tried changing the json so it was [{"name":"1234"},{"name":"134} etc but still no go :(

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to let the server generate the json dynamically depending on the search string. Insert`name_startsWith: request.term` below `maxRows: 25,`. The server can now find the search string in the `name_startsWith` get-variable. For a search string '1' the server might respond with `["1234","134"]`.

Furthermore, delete

```
featureClass: "P",
style: "full",
maxRows: 25,
```

And replace

```
response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
    return {
        label: item.name,
        value: item.name
    }
}));
```

by

```
response(data);
```