# Issue with jQuery AutoComplete using JSON request

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm having some trouble using my autocomplete function. I've succesfully imported jQuery UI.js and my `/form/ajaxcall` file is returning a valid JSON data, but the problem is when filtering the dropdown results.

Method calling:

```
$("[data-maskattribute=autocomplete]").autocomplete({
       source: "/form/ajaxcall",
   });
```

My `ajaxcall` file:

```
[{"label":"Brasil","value":1},{"label":"USA","value":2},{"label":"Portugal","value":3}]
```

So, my dropdown is composed with:

Brasil, USA, Portugal.

The problem is: when I type US (or anything) on the input box, the dropdown shows all the results. If I only type US, it was supposed to show only USA, and if i put `asdf` it shouldn't show anything, right? If i put some manual data on it, works OK. Perhaps is something missing on my code?

I noticed that it's a common issue, by the way I saw a lot of questions about it, but I couldn't proceed with the given answers, i'm not so familiarized to work with AJAX/JSON. Below is one of those.

[jquery autocomplete json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030595/jquery-autocomplete-json)

Thanks in advance and sorry for any mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In remote scenario actual filtering must happen on server side. If your server always returns the same value, then no matter what you type in autocomplete, you'll see same exact values. I've created a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6ugxo7t/) with the code from [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    q: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {  
                    console.log(data);
                    response( data );
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
    });
});
```

If you'll type "USA" in text input, console will show you the array of data, that came from server. And on network tab you'll see that request contains "USA" string as a parameter. You should use it on your server side to do the filtering.

**Edit:**

I thought that you maybe want to load the whole list of countries first and then just use it in autocomplete offline. If so, then you should rewrite your code like this:

```
$.get("/form/ajaxcall", function( data ) { 
        $( "#city" ).autocomplete({ source: data });
});
```

See updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q6ugxo7t/1/). I still make ajax request there, but you can update it with your code.

Comment: Hello @Ilya! Thanks so much for the response. I did the following steps and it still doesn't work, please let me know if i'm doing something wrong:


1 - I used the first function, only putting my field in the .autocomplete function, and switching the ajax URL. Now the dropdown list doesn't pop up.

2 - I tried the second function ($.get...) but when I run, Console throws me an error: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function on jquery-ui at line 6


3 - You said about server-side filtering. If that's the problem, can you please give me some information of how do it on ASP.NET MVC 4? Thx!

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos In second option: do you include scripts in correct order (first is jquery, second is jquery-ui)? Try using this [updated function](http://jsfiddle.net/q6ugxo7t/2/) (but use your actual `data` instead of my dummy).

Comment: Hey @Ilya! Now it worked... Don't know exactly what was the error, but your function did the trick... Thanks!!!

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos, yeah, I think this was because of incorrect syntax first time, my bad. Glad it helped! Could you also [upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) this answer? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, i hadn't did it before because of my low rep, but now I could do it lol

Comment: That'll be our little secret :)